# .NET Core ASP.NET Controller with Session and tests

Tags: asp.net-core, mocking, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my web project in `.NET Core` 2.x. In the Login Controller, after the login, I save a token in the `Session` to have this token across pages.

My problem started when I wanted to test all controllers. If I call a controller from a test, `HttpContext.Session` is `null`.

Then I found this `Mock` for Session

```
public class MockHttpSession : ISession
{
    Dictionary<string, object> sessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public object this[string name]
    {
        get { return sessionStorage[name]; }
        set { sessionStorage[name] = value; }
    }

    string ISession.Id
    {
        get {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    bool ISession.IsAvailable
    {
        get {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    IEnumerable<string> ISession.Keys
    {
        get { return sessionStorage.Keys; }
    }

    void ISession.Clear()
    {
        sessionStorage.Clear();
    }

    Task ISession.CommitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken 
                                      = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    Task ISession.LoadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken 
                                      = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void ISession.Remove(string key)
    {
        sessionStorage.Remove(key);
    }

    void ISession.Set(string key, byte[] value)
    {
        sessionStorage[key] = value;
    }

    bool ISession.TryGetValue(string key, out byte[] value)
    {
        if (sessionStorage[key] != null)
        {
            value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sessionStorage[key].ToString());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can access to the session but for every key I have to read its value like

```
var sessionName = new Byte[20];
bool nameOK = HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("name", out sessionName);
if (nameOK)
    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sessionName);
```

Is there another simple way to save some values for a session across controllers and testable?

**Update**

As you see, with my mock values are in the session but `GetString` returns `System.Byte[]` instead of the value.

[image: With Mock]
[image: With Mock: values are there]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use existing `ISession` extension methods which will probably work with your implementation:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

var result = HttpContext.Session.GetString("name");
```

Check out this class:
https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/SessionExtensions.cs#L32

You can add new as well for your needs

Also check out this question
[How to mock Session Object in asp net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47203333/how-to-mock-session-object-in-asp-net-core)

**UPDATE:**

Looks like your TryGetValue is not consistent with extension methods, which will try to store byte[] into your dictionary. The demon is in that line:

`value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sessionStorage[key].ToString());`
You are using ASCII, not UTF8, also seems like doing some double converting.

I suggest a change for the method like this:

```
bool ISession.TryGetValue(string key, out byte[] value)
{
    object storageValue = null;
    if(sessionStorage.TryGetValue(key, out storageValue))
    {
        var bytes = storageValue as byte[];

        if(bytes != null)
        {
            value = bytes;
            return true;
        }

        value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(storageValue.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    value = null;
    return false;
}
```

You might as well think about using `byte[]` as dictionary value, not an `object`

Comment: Using `object storageValue = null;` won't compile for `TryGetValue()`. Variable declaration needs to be `byte[]`.

Comment: The change done to TryGetValue worked out perfectly... Previously it was returning the type name instead of value and converting that to bytes... Thanks a lot @Curly Brace

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to deal with GetInt32 and SetInt32 extension methods in the unit test. As per the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/SessionExtensions.cs) below is the implementation

```
public static void SetInt32(this ISession session, string key, int value)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[]
            {
                (byte)(value >> 24),
                (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 16)),
                (byte)(0xFF & (value >> 8)),
                (byte)(0xFF & value)
            };
            session.Set(key, bytes);
        }

public static int? GetInt32(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var data = session.Get(key);
            if (data == null || data.Length < 4)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return data[0] << 24 | data[1] << 16 | data[2] << 8 | data[3];
        }
```

so following what's mentioned by  as answer I had to modify little bit as below to handle it.

```
 Mock<ISession> sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
        var key = "FY";
        int fy = 2020;
        var value =  new byte[]
        {
            (byte)(fy >> 24),
            (byte)(0xFF & (fy >> 16)),
            (byte)(0xFF & (fy >> 8)),
            (byte)(0xFF & fy)
        };

  sessionMock.Setup(_ => _.TryGetValue(key, out value)).Returns(true);
```

**I couldn't find this anywhere so sharing here in case it is helpful for someone who are having same issue.**