# How to get session value in integration test .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, integration

I'm trying access session value into integration test, but how get thats done? this my code:

```
    public async Task LoginTest()
    {        
        // Arrange                                    
        var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Email", "email_2_test@mail.com" },
            { "Password", "1234567" }
        };

        // Act
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("/Account/Login", new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData));            

        var actualSessionValue = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("ProfileUser"); // This not work
        Assert.Equal(3212, actualSessionValue)

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Found, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.Equal("/DashboardAdmin", response.Headers.Location.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: You don't. In an integration test, you're looking at a particular input, resulting in a particular output. The whole point is that you don't know or care what's happening in between, because that's the *integration*. If you want to ensure that a particular session value is being set, that's a unit test.

Comment: HttpContext is not available in the test context. try to [Mock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42292876/428061) session state instead of using the real one. consider that you don't want to test ASP.NET session state, you just want to test your App functionality!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;  
var actualSessionValue= (int)(context.Session["ProfileUser"]);
```

Creating an instance of the current HttpContext and returning the value of the ProfileUser's session as an  integer.

Comment: I'm using .net core 2.0, I can`t get current HttpContext.Current direct with statement: HttpContext.Current. I try access HttpContext via DI passing IHttpContextAccessor in constructor, but get error related DI in Xunit "The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data"