# How to moq HttpContext on Asp net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I have an asp .net core project, and practically in each action we use session, my question is how to test it if I don't have sessionRepository. Controller tests crush because session in controller is null. I try to Moq IHttpContextAcessor and it also doesn't work.

I try this:

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://tempuri.org", null), new HttpResponse(null));
```

but HttpContext doesn't contain the definition for Current. (using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;)

Is there any way to moq or test controllers that use HttpContext and sessions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Mock Session variables in ASP.net core unit testing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269770/how-to-mock-session-variables-in-asp-net-core-unit-testing-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock HttpContext for unit testing a .NET core MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400030/mock-httpcontext-for-unit-testing-a-net-core-mvc-controller)

Comment: tnx i will try this.

Comment: tymtam   i set the HttpContext but now in controler i get an exception   

``` Session has not been configured for this application or request. ```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [ControllerContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.controllercontext?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_ControllerContext) to set the context to be  [DefaultHttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.defaulthttpcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.0) which you can modify to your needs.

```
var ctx = new ControllerContext() { HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()};
var tested = new MyCtrl();
tested.ControllerContext = ctx;
```

Comment: this method is only getted  
 ```public HttpContext HttpContext { get; }```

Comment: i set this in this way :
**
var controller = new DashboardController() { ControllerContext = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext()};
            controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
           
            var resp = controller.MainDashboard();
 **

Answer (score 1):

The controller has an Controller context which you can set (i used the default one) :

```
Controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext                                                
{
    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After time I think is bad idea to moq Session, better way is to  create a IOC container, for example we create ISessionManager interface with methods which return stored in session objects:

```
public class SessionManager:ISessionManager{

public User GetUser(){
  User usr= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("USER"));
  return usr;
}

***here we get data from session***

}
```

for UnitTest we just create a new class which implement  ISessionManager and use it for test Controller's.

```
public class SessionManagerTest:ISessionManager{

public User GetUser(){
  User usr=new User();
  ...initialize all fields
  return usr;
}
******
}
```