# Unit tests with NUnit for controller actions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, nunit

I am building a REST API and have some controllers, that i would like to test. The problem is, for post methods, i need to mock the http request.

My post method within the controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] xxx xxx)
    {
       ...

       return Ok(new Link()
       {
           Id = ...,
           Href = GetPath(id)
       });
   }


private string GetPath(int id)
    {
        var displayUrl = UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(Request);
        var urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(displayUrl)
        {
            Query = null,
            Fragment = null
        };
        return urlBuilder.ToString() + "/" + id;
    }
```

As you can see inside the GetPath function there is Request. This is always null and throws errors, when executing the unit test.

My unit test so far (with mocked database):

```
[Test]
    public async Task PostAsync_ReturnsHttpStatus200()
    {
        SaveObject object= new SaveObject
        {
            ...
        };

        var response = await controller.PostAsync(object);

        Assert.That(response, Is.InstanceOf(typeof(OkObjectResult)));
    }
```

I will not show the one time setup, as all the other parts of the unit test seem to work, only the previously explained problem does exist.

How do i mock the request with ASP.Net Core (.Net Core 3.1)?

Comment: For .net Core, you can try answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972693/how-to-moq-httpcontext-on-asp-net-core

Comment: @as.if.i.code I tried it, but now there is an error in the line `new UriBuilder(displayUrl)` because `displayUrl` is ":\\". How do i change this to a random url in order to make it work?

Comment: try setting path as `controllerName.ControllerContext.Request.Path = new PathString("/url");`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone need, here is the solution that worked for OP.
Set controller context and path before calling it inside test.

```cs
Controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext                                                
{
    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
};

Controller.ControllerContext.Request.Path = new PathString("/url");
```